# Burninate [describe]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[describe](/questions/tagged/describe) is a meta tag, has no use, and is typically used for question like "describe what this code does please." ([specimen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795197/decipher-a-while-statement))

It has no tag wiki, and 27 questions.

[image]

Apparently, `describe` is also a SQL keyword. I propose switching this tag out for [sql-describe](/questions/tagged/sql-describe) where relevant, then burning it. (we already have a [git-describe](/questions/tagged/git-describe) tag)

Comment: Nope, it is a keyword in MySQL (or at least from what I see in the list). Clean up is OK, but I don't think it should be burned.

Comment: @nhahtdh Then, [tag:mysql-describe]. We already have [tag:git-describe]. This is just going to be misused if we keep it.

Comment: I think it is a better solution. Can you edit your post?

Comment: @nhahtdh ok, done

Comment: Upon more investigation, it seems that `describe` exists not only in just MySQL. I'd suggest `[sql-describe]`, but I don't know whether people can find this tag to use or not.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree; DESCRIBE is a keyword in most SQL dialects. Removing *all* of them (the RDBMS) you end up with 6 questions; 1 of which should be tagged [git-describe](/questions/tagged/git-describe) (fixed), 2 which shouldn't have it (removed) and 3 questions on r (no idea).

Though this seems a tag that needs cleaning up I don't see what difference you're going to make. As the vast majority of questions relate to databases changing this to [sql-describe](/questions/tagged/sql-describe) (which would, I think, be incorrect as it doesn't seem to be part of the SQL standard) would only split the tag.

It's just one of those tags that needs slightly more policing; there's plenty of them